# How to automatic set name attr. of GUI components?

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I need to set the name attribute of my GUI components to the variable name they are assigned to.
Do you know any eclipse plugin which can perform this?
I thought of using AspectJ but I got no idea how to fetch the variable name for assigning to the name attribute of the according GUI component.

Best regards.

Comment: Can you add an example of the expected behaviour, as there is something unclear about your feature request

Answer (score 0):

I think, databinding is designed for exactly this reason. If you are creating an SWT GUI, you could use [JFace Databinding](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html). Some similar technique should exist for other GUI kits, but I don't know their names.